# Normalize data with outlier inside interval

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I have a dataset with some outliers, which are 10 or 100 times greater than the normal values. I cannot throw out these rows, and I want to normalize this data in an interval `[0, 1]`

First of all, here's what I thought to do:

- Simply rank my dataset's rows and use the ranked positions as variable to normalize. Since we have a uniform distribution here, it is easy. The problem is that the value's differences are not measured, so values with a large difference could have similar normalized values if there aren't intermediate value examples in this dataset
- Use `sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler` method. But I got normalized values between `-0.4` and `300`. It is still not good to normalize something in this scale
- Distribute normalized values between `0` and `0.8` in a linear way for all values where `quantile <= 0.8`, and distribute the values between `0.8` and `1.0` among the remaining values in a similar way to the ranking strategy I mentioned above
- Make a 1D `Kmeans` algorithm to locate all near values and get a cluster with non-outlier values. For these values, I just distribute normalized values between 0 and the quantile value it represents, simply by doing `(value - mean) / (max - min)`, and for the remaining outlier values, I distribute the range between values greater than the quantile and 1 with the ranking strategy
- Create a filter function, like a sigmoid, and multiply values by it. Smaller values remain unchanged, but the outlier's values are approximated to non-outlier values. Then, I normalize it. But how can I design this sigmoid's parameters?

First of all, I would like to get some feedbacks about these strategies, what do you think about them?

And also, how is this problem normally solved? Is there any references to recommend?

Thank you =)